# Repeating operation and using the new value in the new repeated observable

Tags: rx-java

I'm loading stuff from backend and I want something similar to pagination but I can't use .scan to increment the "page" because I actually need to store the last key retrieved by the query and the query is ran after .scan, so I have a catch 22 problem.

My solution so far is a bit hacky, as I assume everything is executed in the same thread and then I wrap everything in an 'Observable.Operator' class so that I can store the needed query key in a member variable (can't store it in a local because of "lambda expression should be effectively final" error.

So my question is: Does anyone know a nice way to carry a variable to the start of the new observable chain once you call retry/repeat (this variable is completely unknown at the start)?

Answer (score 1):

Subjects to the rescue:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject
        .flatMap(page -> Observable.just("stuff for page " + page))
        .subscribe(stuff -> {
            System.out.println("Got stuff = " + stuff);
        });

subject.onNext(1);
subject.onNext(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you ideas (without knowing exactly what you want):

```
final AtomicReference<T> initialValue = new AtomicReference<T>();
final T defaultInitialValue = ...;
Observable.defer(() -> {
    if (initialValue.get() == null) 
        source.scan(defaultInitialValue, accumulator);
    else 
        source.scan(initialValue.get(), accumulator);
  })
  .doOnNext(x -> initialValue.set(x))
  .retry()
  .subscribe(...);
```